# Black Screen after Purple Page when using Integrated Graphics

Tags: nvidia, graphics, login, intel-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I am fairly new to Ubuntu, but love it already.

I recently went into grub and switched back forth between integrated and discrete (nvidia) graphics and now when I boot using the integrated card I get to ubuntu's purple page and then after that the screen goes black and nothing.

I may have accidentally modified some file while trying to follow some advice online, but not sure what files. Maybe "/etc/X11/xorg.conf" but I'm not sure and if so I can't remember what I did to it.

What can I do to get it working again?!?!?

UPDATE: I wanted to add a little more information about my system

- Computer:         Lenovo Thinkpad W520
- System:           Ubuntu 11.04
- Processor:        Intel Core i7-2820QM Processor (2.30GHz, 8MB L3)
- System graphics:  NVIDIA Quadro 2000M Graphics with 2GB DDR3 Memory
- Total memory:     16 GB PC3-10600 DDR3 SDRAM 1333MHz SODIMM Memory (4 DIMM)

Thanks!